# Building Custom Filter to process N requests in M units of time per identifier

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, filter

I am trying to build a custom filter that would process N requests (say 100) ONLY per M unit of time (say 1 second) per identifier. All requests greater than N will be declined or ignored. Request is an object that contains an identifier, time stamp, and other satellite data (filter shouldn't process satellite data).

First thought was to have a ConcurrentHashMap[String, AtomicInteger] which would have the # of requests per identifier but then I am not able to understand which data structure to use to track these count per second and this data structure should also be able to clean up as it would soon grow and we do not need to maintain the data about past.

This also means that a possible solution would have a data structure that has capability to only store delta between time stamps and ensure its not greater than N requests in M units of time per identifier.

This might sound as a rate limiter and there might be standard libraries or options available but I would like to understand how to build it **so looking for some pointers and not direct code solution**.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it.

Store values which are of the form `(time_rounded_off, count)`.  You process a request only if `time_rounded_off = current_time_rounded_off` and `count < max_count`.

When the rounded off time increases, the counter is reset to 0 and you start processing again.

This design is good for keeping a business rule in place, but won't be good if processing a sudden burst of requests is too hard on your infrastructure.  For that I would suggest that you keep an [exponential moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average) of how many requests/second you are processing.  Whenever that drops low enough, you can take another request.

With this approach your values would be pairs of the form `(timestamp, average)`.  Now the process of updating it is to update the timestamp to the current timestamp, and multiply the average by a decay factor (which depends on the difference in timestamps).  And the result if you're getting requests faster than it can handle will be to sample them at the right approximate rate.

You now have two parameters to play with, the decay rate and the average.  You can choose for a particular rate whether that means 360,000 per hour, 6000 per minute, 100 per second, and 10 per 0.1 seconds.  The difference between them is the potential size of a "burst" that you have to process at a single go.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at Guava's [RateLimiter](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html) class.

It's  library class but the javadoc explains pretty well how it works internally.

The very short version is : it works a bit like a `Semaphore`. Threads (needing to handle a request) must acquire a permit from the RateLimiter before being allowed to do so. The `RateLimiter` ouputs permits at a predefined rate.

You can check the source code here : https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.java